# Create folder in Android View

Tags: android-studio

I want create a folder for java source code that is visible in the "Android" view. This is not an asset or layout or res folder. Just a simple folder that becomes visible and accessible.

I know how to create a new folder but it's only visible in the "Project" view. I never see it in the "Android" view.

[image]

Comment: why you want to create folder?

Comment: For better organization of my code files. I don't want everything all in one folder. I want a folder for Fragments, Adapters and so forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java, folders are called packages. You can create a folder for your source code in the *java* folder by right clicking it and selecting new>Package.

It is important to note that classes in different packages can only access public members.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: That's what I was looking for Thanks!

Comment: I noticed when I first create a Project, under the Java folder there are three packages. One for the main, a androidTest and Test package folder. Can I just delete those 2 "Test" packages?

Comment: Yes. Those are for putting your UnitTest and InstrumentedTest files. If you are not building Unit tests or Instrumented tests to validate your project then you don't need those folders.